# Make command Fatal Error

Tags: makefile, cmake, clang

I'm installing [cppinsights](https://github.com/andreasfertig/cppinsights) C++ ClangAST based Tool. I can able to build the
source project with cmake but when I run make command the process get's failed.

The command I used to build the project is :

***CMAKE -STEP***

- cmake ../cppinsights -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/home/praveen/ninja/bin/clang++ -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/praveen/ninja/bin

The output of this command is :

The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 6.0.0

-- Check for working CXX compiler: /home/praveen/ninja/bin/clang++

-- Check for working CXX compiler: /home/praveen/ninja/bin/clang++ -- works

-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info

-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done

-- Detecting CXX compile features

-- Detecting CXX compile features - done

-- Found LLVM_CONFIG_PATH: /home/praveen/ninja/bin/llvm-config
```

//LLVM LIBRARY stuff's

llvm_config(LLVM_LIBDIR)=>/home/praveen/ninja/lib;

```
-- llvm_config(LLVM_INCLUDE_DIR)=>/home/praveen/llvm-novice/llvm/include;

-- llvm_config(LLVM_SYSTEM_LIBS)=>;

-- llvm_config(LLVM_PACKAGE_VERSION)=>6.0.0svn;

-- Git repo url: https://github.com/andreasfertig/cppinsights.git

-- Git commit hash: 5ce053d3f7bbd7dc0382385a499be13c99b67005

-- Generating version.h

-- Found clang-tidy: /home/praveen/ninja/bin/clang-tidy

-- Stripping executable

-- Found Doxygen: /usr/local/bin/doxygen (found version "1.8.14") found
```

components:  doxygen dot

```
-- Using CXX: /home/praveen/ninja/bin/clang++

-- Configuring done

-- Generating done

-- Build files have been written to: /home/praveen/cppinsight/build_00/build
```

***MAKE - STEP***

When I run "make" command it throws an error like this

> [  7%] Building CXX object
>   CMakeFiles/insights.dir/AutoStmtHandler.cpp.o
>
> In file included from
>   /home/praveen/cppinsight/build_00/cppinsights/AutoStmtHandler.cpp:8:
>
> /home/praveen/cppinsight/build_00/cppinsights/./AutoStmtHandler.h:11:10:
>   fatal error: 'clang/AST/AST.h' file not found
>
> ```
>      #include "clang/AST/AST.h"
> ```
>
> 1 error generated.
>
> CMakeFiles/insights.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target
>
> 'CMakeFiles/insights.dir/AutoStmtHandler.cpp.o' failed
>
> make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/insights.dir/AutoStmtHandler.cpp.o] Error 1
>
> CMakeFiles/Makefile2:131: recipe for target
>   'CMakeFiles/insights.dir/all' failed
>
> make[1](https://github.com/andreasfertig/cppinsights): *** [CMakeFiles/insights.dir/all] Error 2
>
> Makefile:129: recipe for target 'all' failed
>
> make: *** [all] Error 2

I don't know why the build files are not including the source directory while creating the makefiles.

And please note that

- /home/praveen/ninja is the build directory of LLVM
- /home/praveen/llvm-novice is the source directory of LLVM.

LLVM_LIBDIR is /home/praveen/ninja/lib

LLVM_INCLUDE_DIR is /home/praveen/llvm-novice/llvm/include

So What steps I have to do, to get the build process right?

Thanks

Comment: Does the file AST.h exist in your source directory? Is it maybe supposed to be generated?

Comment: Actually AST.h doesn't exist in that directory but instead, it is in this directory /home/praveen/llvm-novice/llvm/tools/clang/include/clang/AST.